# Automation on the site using seleniumrequests

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I am trying to automate some processes on the site. At first I tried to use queries, but a captcha came in response. Now I'm using selenium queries, and here's the problem: when I log in using selenium tools only, everything works fine, but I can't add coupons on the site and confirm them.

```
from seleniumrequests import Firefox

driver = Firefox()

user = '000000'
password = '000000'
driver_1x.get("https://1xstavka.ru/")

driver.find_element_by_id('curLoginForm').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('auth_id_email').send_keys(user)
driver.find_element_by_id('auth-form-password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('auth-button__text').click()
```

But if you use:

```
from seleniumrequests import Firefox

driver = Firefox()

driver.request('GET', 'https://1xstavka.ru')
```

The window opens for a second and immediately closes, a 200 response is received, but there are no cookies. It's the same with publishing requests, with which I'm trying to automate the process. After the request for publication, the response is 200, but nothing happens on the site.

```
driver.request('POST', 'https://1xstavka.ru/user/auth', json=json)
```

please tell me what is wrong or how you can solve this problem

Comment: What is `driver_1x` ?

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to access the URL specified in the query; but for captcha/coupons, I created a loop with an interim stop function. This gives me the chance to input it manually and then continue the loop.

Comment: if through selenium, captcha is not a problem. Namely, that it is not possible to send requests through selenium requests. Website https://1xbet.mg/ru/?cdnOff=1, 1xstavka russian region

Comment: what else can I do with requests?

Comment: Try changing the url slightly by removing "?cdnOff=1" . The portal opens quite well and elements are accessible. (tried id = registration_ref_code, works fine)